# image viewer: mouse wheel to move back and forward

Tags: 11.10, shortcuts, shotwell, eog, mouse-wheel

In the gnome image viewer (3.2.0), I would like to change these shortcuts for next/prev image to use the mousewheel.  I would also like to change it in shotwell if possible.  Current the mousewheel is assigned to zoom in/out on the current image, which I almost never need.

I've tried setting on `desktop/gnome/interface/can_change_accels` in `gconf-editor` but no luck.

I have found where I think I should edit, in `~/.config/eog/accels`, there are lines like

```
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MenuActionsGallery/GoPrevious" "<Alt>Left")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MenuActionsGallery/GoNext" "<Alt>Right")
```

Which I guess I should uncomment (remove semicolon) and assign to something else, but what could be the accel for mouse wheel events?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dumped eog, instead using `gthumb` [image: Install gthumb].  The mousewheel has, by default, the sensible behaviour I was trying to get eog/shotwell to use, and as an added bonus it is seemingly much faster at rendering images too.

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin available to do this:

[eog plugin Bad Mouse Wheel](http://fliggs.wordpress.com/eog-plugin-bad-mouse-wheel/)

Its called bad, because the eog-developers love another mouse behaviour....

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, this isn't possible without modifying the Eye of GNOME source code.

`accels` is an abbreviation of "keyboard accelerators," and there is no way to associate these with mouse button events.